# Checking and deducting points using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a very simple problem for you geniuses. I am trying to use a php code to check my database, to see if a user has enough points. Then if they have enough points, then deduct the points from there account.
This is what I'm currently using that is not working:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id177667_root", "***", "id177667_loginb");
    $response = array();
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $_POST["username"]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $password, $points);
    $pointsint = (int)$points;

    if ($pointsint > 12500){
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE user SET points = points - ? WHERE username = ?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "is", 12500, $_POST["username"]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $password, $points);  

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
            $response["success"] = true;  
            $response["name"] = $name;
            $response["username"] = $username;
        }
    }else{
        $response["success"] = false;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Not enough time right now to look for your problem, but as a advise: Dont select all data from Users. There is no need to Select * From ... why not simply "Select points FROM user" ? Rella no need to load the password and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do that in SQL without the first `SELECT` command like:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `points` = (
    CASE
        WHEN `points` > 12500 THEN `points` = `points` - ?
        ELSE `points`=`points`
    END
) WHERE username = ?
```